# help with installation of linux fedora

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, partition, system-installation

[image]

As you can see my hard drive size is 298.09 **GiB**.

[image]

Look I have `free space`166.61 **GiB**. If I use Automatic method to install linux fedora will it automatically take the space of `free space`. There was Linux Mint also. Linux Mint is still right there. So, what I have to do to install Linux Fedora alongside Windows inside `free space`? Will it ok If I click on automatic. I thought custom should be better. When I clicked on custom I didn't understand anything. Cause, there was no function(no method). I didn't understand anything then.

Comment: You say that Linux Mint is still there, but I don't see where. On the other hand, automatic installation will indeed go to that green free space. No need for custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, autopart will use the 166 GiB of free space to install Fedora. I don't see a Linux Mint installation on your drive, only Windows and one possibly unused 975 MiB partition but that is too small for Mint.

Manual partitioning in the Anaconda installer works in a different way than most partitioning tools -- you start with mount point (e.g. `/home`) and continue with specifying other "properties" of it, including size, filesystem type, encryption etc. The *Advanced Custom* option provides "GParted-style" partitioning tool, but requires better knowledge of storage technologies.

The automatic partitioning option should work fine here, but if you really want to do manual partitioning, I recommend reading the [Manual Partitioning section of Fedora Installation Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning) first. Documentation is also available in the installer environment for both manual partitioning methods.

Comment: I was using Linux mint right there. I installed mint directly to that disk by automatically install mint alongside windows. I had grub loader issue earlier. As far as I saw some people said that Linux isn't visible to windows. When I had grub loader issue than there was grub loader to load my disk(Linux mint). So, I think I have to do as you said